# Nodejs cannot connect to Postgresdb container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker-compose

I am currently working on an angular app using Rest API (Express, Nodejs) and Postgresql.  Everything worked well when hosted on my local machine.  After testing, I moved the images to Ubuntu server so the app can be hosted on an external port.  I am able to access the angular frontend using the https://serveripaddress:80 but when trying to login, the api is not connecting to Postgresql.  I am getting an error message: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.  Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.0' 

services:

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: myDatabase
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myPwd
      POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
      POSTGRES_HOST: db

    ports:
    - 5434:5432
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  backend: # name of the second service
   image: myid/nodeapi
   ports:
   - 3000:3000

   environment:
    POSTGRES_DB: myDatabase
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myPwd
    POSTGRES_PORT: 5432
    POSTGRES_HOST: db
   depends_on:
   - db
   command: bash -c "sleep 20 && node server.js"

  myapp-portal:
    image: myId/angular-app
    ports:
    - "80:80"
    depends_on:
    - backend

volumes:
      postgres-data:
```

The code to connect to database:

```
const { Client } = require('pg')


const client = new Client({
  database: process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
  user: 'postgres',
  password: process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.POSTGRES_HOST,
  port: process.env.POSTGRES_PORT

})

client.connect()
.then(
  () => {
      console.log("db connected");
  })
```

and the docker-compose log for backend:

backend_1           | db connected

When I exec into the database docker container and connect to psql, I see that my database is created(used pg_dump manually) with all the tables and data.  My guess is that node.js is connecting to the default Postgres database created at the time of the installation.  I had the same issue on my local machine but I resolved it by creating a new server group in pgAdmin4 and creating a new db on port 5434.  I prefer not to do this on server as it defeats the purpose of the concept of docker.  Another thought is perhaps node.js is attempting to connect to the database even before it is up.  That is the reason I added the line 'sleep 20' which worked on my local machine.  Any thoughts on how I can fix this?  TIA!

Comment: I suppose that you already tried with `docker-compose build` in case of changing values in docker-compose.yml

Comment: @Nikolay - Yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait on the availability of a host and TCP port, you can use this script https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it
In your docker file you can copy this file into container and change mode

```
RUN chmod +x wait-for-it.sh
```

Then in your docker compose run this script on service which you want to wait

```
entrypoint: bash -c "./wait-for-it.sh --timeout=0 service_name:service_port && node server.js"
```

Comment: I have tried that before I posted the question and tried it again now.  Still no luck.  It works fine when I connect to the server and run the app from my machine but when I try it from another computer or phone it gives me the error message - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.  Any thoughts?